# I need to write a function "checkArray" which receives an array of random numbers and return the sum of the numbers bigger than 5

Tags: javascript, function, random

I need to write a function "checkArray" which receives an array of random numbers (created with giveMeRandom) and prints, for each item, whether it's bigger than 5.
The function returns the sum of the numbers bigger than 5.

```
const checkArray = function(n) {
    let sum = 0;
    let newArr = [];

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        newArr.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)); 
        if (newArr[i] > 5) {
            sum += newArr[i]
        }
        return sum;
    }

    return newArr;
}

console.log(checkArray(6));
```

Actually it does not work

Comment: Can you provide the function`giveMeRandom` also? And `checkArray` receives a `number` not an array.

Comment: You say it should receive an array of numbers but in your example it only receives a single number, which one is it?

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you need?

```js
const checkArray = function(n) {
    let sum = 0;
    let newArr = [];

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        newArr.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)); 
        if (newArr[i] > 5) {
            sum += newArr[i]
        }
    }

    return sum;
}

console.log(checkArray(6));
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you copied the code from the giveMeRandom instead of writing a new function. This should do what you described.

```js
// n should be an array of numbers
const checkArray = function(n) {
    return n.reduce(function (sum, num) {
      if (num > 5) {
        console.log(num  + " is greater than 5");
        return sum + num;
      }
      
      return sum;
    }, 0)
}

console.log(checkArray([4, 5, 6, 7]));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkArray(a) {
  var total = a
  .filter((e) => e > 5)
  .reduce((sum, e) => {
    return sum + e;
  });
  return total;
}
```